# Azure Logic Apps - Service Bus - Receive message action is always skipped

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I am testing for the first time the Azure Service Bus integration with Logic Apps.
To run an easy sample, I've created a queue in a Service Bus, and two logic apps: the first one writes a message in the queue every minute, the second one reads a message every minute.
The first app works fine, and I can see that my one and only queue gets populated with messages. The second app, instead, always return status "skipped" on the trigger, as if the queue was empty, even though I can clearly see from the Azure Portal that the queue is not empty.

The messages also seem to be removed by the active queue and moved to the Dead Letter queue with reason MaxDeliveryCountExceeded.

Since there are not many options to play around with in the Azure logic app designer, and this is a very basic example, I am at a loss to where I might be wrong. I am sure it is something simple, but I just can't make it work.

Here is what gets returned by the app that tries to read the queue:

[Skipped list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqAJ0.png)

[Skipped trigger details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd0qa.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, as a mistake, I put the lock timeout as only 1 sec when I created my queue. This was not enough to process the messages by my app (which was sending a test email via Outlook.com connector). The messages then was put in the dead letter queue and the app showed the trigger as "skipped".

Comment: Thanks for circling back - I'm currently writing up a step-by-step tutorial and video on Service Bus + Logic Apps, so feel free to ping me for any questions and I'll help where I can (or document better where needed) -- logicappsemail@microsoft.com

Comment: Thank you @jeffhollan I will have to work extensively in the next few weeks on a project that involves Service Bus + Logic Apps, so I will let you know in case I run into problems or if I can offer some input on the currently available documentation.

Comment: @jeffhollan Did you manage to write up the Service Bus and Logic App tutorial? Would be very handy right about now :)